# Setting up customizable power options for different activities (reading, listening to music, etc.)

Tags: power-management, profile

How can I set up various configurations of customized power options for different activities?

Settings I would like to configure:

- Reading Mode -> screen never goes to sleep, low performance, dim light (for long battery life and to continue reading)
- Music Mode -> screen dims, but computer does not sleep (for long battery life and to continue listening to music)

I have an Asus Notebook with Windows 8.1.

Any suggestions? Are there applications that do so? Or could I create custom 'Power Plans' in addition to the ones that Windows comes with? I know I can customize those, but I would like to create my own titled 'Reading Mode', 'Music Mode', etc. Or is it better for me to just use these?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or could I create custom 'Power Plans' in addition to the ones that Windows comes with?

That's definitely something you could do.  Microsoft provides this nice document to get you started: [Create a Custom Power Plan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh825681.aspx).

Excerpt:

1. Click **Start**, and then select **Control Panel**.
2. Click **Hardware and Sound**, and then select **Power Options**.
3. The Power Options Control Panel opens, and the power plans appear.
4. Click **Create a power plan**.
5. Follow the on-screen instructions to create and customize a power plan file that is based on an existing plan.

Comment: Thank you so very much! Didn't realize this was an option.